# Set default permissions for files received via SFTP

Tags: linux, permissions, openssh, sftp, acl

I'm receiving files pushed from another system via SFTP to a directory on a Linux VM. These files get the wrong permissions `u=rw g= o=`. However I need those files to have permissions like `u=rw g=rw o=`.

I have read a lot of articles suggesting to adjust the `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` file like this: `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0002` OR `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002`. I've restarted the server with `sudo systemctl restart sshd`. However changing this setting does not have effect on the default permissions of the received files. Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

The `sftp-server` "-u" option sets the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for the server process. The umask affects the default permissions for files created by the server process. An SFTP client can send explicit SFTP protocol commands to override the permissions and set them to what the client requests. It's possible that you're seeing that.

Modern versions of `sftp-server` have an option "-P" to disable individual SFTP protocol messages. You could try using that to disable the commands sent by clients to set file permissions. The two messages are "setstat" and "fsetstat". To disable them,
add this to the `sftp-server` or `internal-sftp` subsystem line:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002 -Psetstat,fsetstat
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you get an error, try running "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests" to list the supported request types. If you get an error, your SFTP server software may be too old to support the "-P" option.

After making the change, you should test with an SFTP client (the same one being used by your users) to make sure the change has the desired effect that the SFTP client behaves reasonably.

Some documentation:

- [The sftp-server manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server)
- [The SFTP RFC](https://www.openssh.com/txt/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02.txt). Refer to section 6.2.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!
Running "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests" gave me following output: `open close read write lstat fstat setstat fsetstat opendir readdir remove mkdir rmdir realpath stat rename readlink symlink posix-rename statvfs fstatvfs hardlink fsync lsetstat`. So `-Psetstat,fsetstat` should be supported.
However changing the subsystem line as you suggested did not have any influence on the default permissions.

Comment: Does it maybe have something to do with the ACL permissions on the directory where I receive the files pushed via SFTP?
I have set them like this:
# file: .
# owner: user1
# group: sftp_group
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r--
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r--

Comment: The clients can (and do) specify the permissions in the "open" request too. And you cannot block that request obviously, without blocking uploads (and downloads) completely. For details, see my answer to [Does OpenSSH SFTP server use umask or preserve client side permissions after put command (chrooted environment)?](https://serverfault.com/q/639042/168875) Also [How to specify file permission when putting a file using OpenSSH sftp command](https://serverfault.com/q/283492/168875).

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl, so as I understood in your answers: The umask can only remove permissions from the file and not add permissions. Do you know if there is any possibility to set (higher) default permissions when the source file has lower ones? So for e.g. I want to transfer a file via SFTP which has permissions 600 at source but once the file got pushed to the target directory of my Linux VM I want it to have permissions 660 by default.

Comment: @Niklas I'm not aware of such option.

Comment: Thanks for your information @MartinPrikryl.
Ok, for me the "workaround" would be to just use the same user of the received  file (read-write permissions) for my further processing. Then I don't have to rely on group permissions of that file.